# Centrally maintainable projects

Tags: workflow, design, architecture

I am trying to come up with a technical architecture for the below requirement.

We have a requirement where a site/workspace/app needs to be automatically created per project. Per project a SharePoint library should exist and be enhanced with a set of properties by default. There is also a project page. Moreover, the data over the different projects needs to be maintainable in one place centrally. Also, A set of templates are to be maintained centrally. If a new project is created, it should contain the default templates. If these are updated centrally, the unused versions in the created projects should be updated as well. Mass changes should be possible to change properties (e.g. of a content type) over different projects.

How can this be achieved? Do we need custom workflows for this? To what extent can out of the box components be used?

Thanks for letting me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things you are requesting so covering all of them in a detail goes to a level where one should get paid for doing it!

I'd recommend to:

- **Create a site template for your project site.** This way you can have default libraries with configured properties such as document templates included once the site is create. A site template can also include your project page.
- **Create your (document) templates to the core of your site collection and refer to them at your project site template.** This way, if the template changes, it doesn't have to be referred again on each project site.
- **Use site content types created at the root of your site collection as much as possible.** These can be used as *metadata* for your project site's items. Once your project sites have the same content types in use, you can create useful queries at the root of your site collection. This should cover the "*the data over the different projects needs to be maintainable in one place centrally*" -requirement

If there are more specific needs, you should edit the question and explain them in more detail. Note, that asking a single question at once tends to lead to a higher chance for getting an answer.